# error while linking with ffmpeg under windows using VC 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, dll, ffmpeg

I am writing a project on windows that uses opencv (3.2.0 compiled from sources).

I am trying to add ffmpeg to my project in order to use it to save a mpeg file; since compiling ffmpeg-3.3.[34] is quite a cumbersome process on windows (i do not currently have mingw or yasm installed) i decided to give the binary packages a try. (downloaded both dev and shared packages from ffmpeg.zeranoe.com)

Since there were not differentiated dll for "debug" and "release" mode i put them in a common path that would be picked by both visual studio compiling mode.

When running my project in "debug" mode everything is fine, while after having compiled the "release" version i get the following error when launching the executable

The error encountered is: (translated from italian so please bear with some imprecise wording) Impossible to find the entry point ?fastFree@cv@YAXPAX@Z of the procedure in the dll avcodec-57.dll

Can anyone point me in the right direction? how come the dll complains about a missing symbol only in "release" mode? also, the signature of the symbol seems to be related to opencv library, but how on earth is this possible? since opencv was already in the project and is not interacting with ffmpeg?

Comment: You probably have the binary packages in the Debug folder, and not in the Release folder. Go to where the builds are and make sure the binaries are also in the Release folder.

Comment: @Serkan, no the same files are in both release and debug. However if that was the case then the error would have been the application complaining about a missing lib. Not a lib complaining about a missing symbol